# "Edit your answer draft" button is still there after discarding the draft in Android app

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, draft

How to reproduce:

1. Open any question and click "Add an answer"
2. Type anything, and go back to the question; "Edit your answer draft" button will appear
3. Press "X" beside it and discard the draft
4. The draft is discarded, but the button is still there. (!)
5. When the button is clicked, the Answer box is empty (correct, since the draft has been discarded)

What I expect: Hide "Edit your answer draft" button since the draft is empty anyway.

- Stack Exchange: 1.0.12
- Android model: Nexus 4
- Android version: 4.4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed in version 1.0.16, sorry about that. It was due to some bug fixes with screen rotations that I had done a while back but I forgot to make the logic here use the new methods I had set up.